# Regex: How to retrieve a string that contains .php follow by query string

Tags: php, regex

As per title above, do you guys have any idea that can retrieve the image source that look like the pattern as follows?

http://www.google.com/test.php?uid=12345

*Note: for the query string value it can be anything but before the query string value, it suppose to be a fixed string.

My current regex look like this...

```
/(<img[^>]*src=".*?(?:\.php\^)"[^>]*>)/i
```

Million thanks if you can really help on this :)

Comment: Erm no man, how are you going to get the SRC value from the img tag with the parse-url?

Comment: It was confusing, since you didn't say you are searching for the link in a HTML page.

Comment: I did? if you have time, please read it again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/(<img[^>]*src=".*?\.php(?:[^"]*)"[^>]*>)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use XPATH DOM parser for get all the element and content from given url.

**Here are simple example for you**

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
@$html->loadHtmlFile('write your url here');
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );

$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//div[@class='product-image']/img/@src" );

foreach ($nodelist1 as $n1){
    echo $n1->nodeValue;
}
```

**Explanation of this line :** //div[@class='product-image']/img/@src
find where your img tag inside the web page using inspect element or page view source. here my image tag is inside div tag which class attributes name is product-image.

For more info about XPATH please visit :
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp
http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/xpath.html

Just try it.....thanks....p2c